# pgAdmin4 not working anymore after restarting PC

Tags: python, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have a strange problem. I followed [this](https://linuxhint.com/install-pgadmin4-ubuntu/) tutorial to install pgAdmin4 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. It works fine until i restart my PC.

When I try to run  `python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py` from my `~/pgadmin4` directory, it prints this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py", line 34, in <module>
    import config
  File "/home/myUsername/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_PY2, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "/home/myUsername/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/nodes.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 647, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
ImportError: No module named markupsafe
```

I've already installed several modules (before markupsafe, many others were missing) using pip. But there is always a new one missing every time I try to rerun it.

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Looking forward to reading some answers and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look at the tutorial you linked and it seems that it installed the needed libraries in a Python [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).
What happened, I guess, is that you forgot to *activate* the virtualenv (a isolated environment) after the reboot.

Specifically, as per the tutorial:

```
$ cd pgAdmin4
$ source bin/activate
```

That should fix all the links and executables for the packages that you installed in the virtualenv.

<s>As you asked for other ways to do this (avoid having to type it every time), you could just run your script using the *virtualenv* interpreter. So, what you could do, is to directly use that specific one instead of the one in your global `$PATH` (when you run `python` in the terminal, that is the one you use). To do so, in this specific case, it is enough for you to `cd` into the `pgAdmin4` virtualenv directory and run:

`bin/python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py`</s>

Comment: Thanks, that works! But I have to type it every time i restart my PC. Do you know how I can make it permanent?

Comment: Hi Jakob, I have just updated my answer to be more complete. Please, let me know if this suits better your use-case.

Comment: Hi Marco, I don't get your answer. Could you explain it?

Comment: Hi, I have tried to improve the explanation a bit. Basically, as you asked for it, I gave you an option to avoid having to repeat the `source bin/activate` at each reboot: using the interpreter in the `bin` directory of the virtualenv. What _activate_ script does it's more detailed here: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#activate-script
Long story short, it will rewrite your `$PATH` to use the interpreter located inside the virtualenv.

Comment: sorry but when executing the command above it doesn't work after reboot

Comment: I am truly sorry it did not work, it sure did for me in the past. If I may, I'd like to point you to [systemd unit-files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), so you could create a service, which might be more reliable and flexible than an alias.

Comment: I've already figured out a different solution. Thanks for your help, i appreciate it. Liebe Grüße aus Österreich :)